# Need help in display members name when logged in using PHP?

Tags: php

for some r.eason I cant display a logged in users name when they are logged in? the code is below

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

echo '<?php if (isset($_SESSION[\'first_name\'])) { echo ", {$_SESSION[\'first_name\']}!"; } ?>';   
if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
    echo 'something else';
}
 } else { echo 'something';
}
?>
```

Thanks every one but i solved it.

Comment: Looks like you'd have loads of fun with `eval()` :P

Answer (score 1):

Ack! Just look at your code. Do you know what this line is doing?

```
echo '<?php if (isset($_SESSION[\'first_name\'])) { echo ", {$_SESSION[\'first_name\']}!"; } ?>';
```

That's so wrong I don't even know where to begin. Just try

```
echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
```

And see if that gets you closer to what you want ;)

Comment: Then print_r($_SESSION) and see if the username is even set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're also calling session_start() before trying to access the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
    echo ", " . $_SESSION['first_name']} . '!';    
  if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
    echo 'something else';
  }
} else {
  echo 'something';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid PHP code. Single quote "'" are not pair up. The block ('{' and '}') are also not pairing up.

The most importantly, the code to show the first name is in a string so it will not be shown.

I think the code you are trying to write is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
        echo ", {$_SESSION['first_name']}!";
    }
    if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1) {
        echo 'something else';
    }
} else {
    echo 'something';
}
?>l
```

Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of possibilities of the mistakes and make sure that you have corrected them

1) have you set the **cookie "first_name" using setcookie** method...?

2) Then have u called the ***session_start()*** function so that the session variables can be called in that page??

3) Try **echo $_SESSION['first_name']**... i don understand why you have put the flower brackets coz i never have used them even once in my **15 php projects**..

Comment: `first_name` is not a cookie. It's a session variable. If you're nesting variables with single quotes in a double quoted string, you *should* indeed wrap them in "flower" brackets, ie, echo "x = {$_SESSION['x']}";